# How can fill button/view background some percentage of size?

Tags: android, button, colors, fill

I want to make view to fill some percentage like 70% of button size.So, Is it possible in android? I need the view like attached below image.

[image: Survey Module]

Comment: use seek bar to implement this

Comment: @BirajZalavadia, Thanks for reply. Is it possible to display label also in seek bar.

Comment: you nee to use two views say textview and seekbar. Using framelayout or relativelayouy overlap textview with seekbar with transparent background

Comment: You'd want it to fill from 0 to 100, btw..

Comment: @DaniSpringer, Thanks  for response. Yes fill from 0 to 100, I did using seekbar by set the progress as per required and set the custom color.